# apk crashes continuously on device while using android studio

Tags: java, android, crash, apk

normal apk with simple textview is crashing on device continuously while using android studio, some time that apk run and without any modification sometimes that apk start crashing

help me to solve this problem

here is the log cat

> 08-22 16:43:12.070 13344-13344/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   08-22 16:43:12.080 13344-13344/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
>   08-22 16:43:12.086 13344-13344/? V/BoostFramework: mAcquireFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])
>   08-22 16:43:12.086 13344-13344/? V/BoostFramework: mReleaseFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()
>   08-22 16:43:12.086 13344-13344/? V/BoostFramework: mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
>   08-22 16:43:12.086 13344-13344/? V/BoostFramework: mIOPStart method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
>   08-22 16:43:12.086 13344-13344/? V/BoostFramework: mIOPStop method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()
>   08-22 16:43:12.091 13344-13344/? V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@13ff4db
>   08-22 16:43:12.122 13344-13344/com.psquare.tdupdate W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.psquare.tdupdate-2/lib/arm64
>   08-22 16:43:12.133 13344-13344/com.psquare.tdupdate I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.psquare.tdupdate, real application class is null.
>   08-22 16:43:12.214 13344-13344/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.psquare.tdupdate-2/lib/arm64
>   08-22 16:43:12.219 13344-13344/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

```
                                               --------- beginning of crash
```

> 08-22 16:43:12.220 13344-13344/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.psquare.tdupdate, PID: 13344
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mAssets in class Landroid/content/res/MiuiResourcesImpl; (declaration of 'android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5431)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1563)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6195)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mAssets in class Landroid/content/res/MiuiResourcesImpl; (declaration of 'android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
>                                                          at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources(MonkeyPatcher.java:442)
>                                                          at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.onCreate(BootstrapApplication.java:308)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1025)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5428)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1563) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6195) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764) 
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mAssets in class Landroid/content/res/MiuiResourcesImpl; (declaration of 'android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
>                                                          at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources(MonkeyPatcher.java:433)
>                                                          at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.onCreate(BootstrapApplication.java:308) 
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1025) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5428) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1563) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6195) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764) 
>   08-22 16:43:12.222 13344-13344/? E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
>   08-22 16:43:12.229 13344-13344/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13344 SIG: 9

Comment: Show MiuiResourcesImpl class

Comment: not understood @DEADMC

Comment: is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Well seems like you are using mAssets field from MiuiResourcesImpl  class but looks like MiuiResourcesImpl  doesnt contain that field.

Comment: this problem is coming after update to android 7 in mi

Comment: then what should I do @DEADMC

Answer (score 1):

After changing the   minSdkVersion  to 14 in build.gradle  the issue gets resolved

Answer (score 0):

After updateing MIUI 9 (Android 7) on Xiaomi phone I facing this too.

my minSDK is 14.....
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: Now, after getting this error, I just restart the Android Studio and run the app again. Then it works fine. I hope it will be solved in stable MIUI 9 which will be released in this month.